# File path error for .json file, showing no such file or directory

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, next.js, web-development-server

It is unable to read a .json file, showing no such file or directory.

```
import * as fs from 'fs';

export default function handler(req, res) {
  fs.readFile("../../blogdata/file1.json", 'utf-8', (err, data)=>{
    console.log('');
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      res.status(500).json({ error: err });
      return;
    }
    res.status(200).json( JSON.parse(data) )
  })
}
```

I've tried every possible path, still not working.

```
wait  - compiling /api/blogs (client and server)...
event - compiled successfully in 58 ms (65 modules)
API resolved without sending a response for /api/blogs, this may result in stalled requests.

[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '../../blogdata/file1.json'] {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: '../../blogdata/file1.json'
}
```

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/JENX2.png)

Comment: Add the code that you have tried along with the exact error message in the question (not as an image).

Comment: Please post code, not Images of code

Comment: Add a `console.log(process.cwd())` to see what your current working directory. All paths you pass to `fs.readFile` or similar are resolved relative to that directory